# Select distinct users with referrals

Tags: database, django, django-models

I have a bunch of `Users`. Since Django doesn't really let me extend the default `User` model, they each have `Profiles`.  The Profiles have a `referred_by` field (a FK to User). I'm trying to get a list of Users with >= 1 referral.  Here's what I've got so far

```
Profile.objects.filter(referred_by__isnull=False).values_list('referred_by', flat=True)
```

Which gives me a list of IDs of the users who have referrals... but I need it to be *distinct*, and I want the `User` object, not their ID.

Or better yet, it would be nice if it could return the number of referrals a user has.

Any ideas?

Comment: for your queryset to be distinct you can simply use .distinct(): http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: @vitorbal: I know about `distinct()` but only the `referred_by` field needs to be distinct. This doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a long time to wrap my head around this, but I think I finally got it figured out:

```
affiliates = User.objects.annotate(num_referrals=Count('referrals')).filter(num_referrals__gt=0)
```

I didn't think I'd be able to use the reverse relationship

```
 referred_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='referrals')
```

in `Count()`, nor did I think you could use the annotated value in the filter... that's pretty cool. I still wish you could use GROUP BY without having to annotate stuff (assuming I didn't need the count).